# combined use of bash options for error handling (e.g. pipefail, errexit, inherit_errexit)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, exit-code

Consider the following Bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit pipefail
shopt -s inherit_errexit

( echo hello ; exit 1 ) | cat

echo world
```

Running with version 5.0.17, the output is as follows:

```
hello
world
```

However, the subshell responsible for printing `hello` would have failed, with a nonzero exit status. Part of a pipe,  with enabling the option`pipefail`, the entire pipe should similarly fail, with the same status (the subsequent item in the pipe of course returning a zero status by itself). Thus, the pipe should evaluate to a nonzero status, which due to `errexit` (if not `inherit_errexit` as well) would prompt the immediate termination of the script, without reaching the final statement printing `world`.

As seen, the prediction is not accurate that the final print statement is not reached.

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're only setting the `errexit` setting, not `pipefail`. You can't put multiple options after `-o`, you need to repeat the `-o` option. Everything else is being put into the positional arguments.

So change

```
set -o errexit pipefail
```

to

```
set -o errexit -o pipefail
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on whether close-as-typo applies here? If not appropriate, I would be tempted to try to come up with a question title that would make sure that (only) folks making the same mistake find the question.

Comment: Tempting, but I think this is a reasonable misunderstanding of the `set` syntax, and a useful answer.

Comment: Please keep open. The question is more than an isolated mistake by one person. It is easy even for a seasoned developer to have an idea in his head about the semantics being such as I thought, and an idea of such a kind tends to stick. Without another human spotting the mistake, I doubt I would ever have discovered it.

Comment: The error wasn't initially obvious to me.

Comment: I agree. It's a mistake I've actually made before, in fact, here I go now to fix an instance of it I wrote just last week... :D

Comment: I updated the title to more closely represent the problem.